# In system settings - network settings

Tags: networking

Network settings screen will not stay open to turn wireless hardware device on or turn airplane mode off
ubuntu updates will not install updates, error message no internet conection, but my laptop has internet by high speed ethernet cable direct to router/modem at 1000Mb/s

Answer (score 0):

can you provide some helpful errors so that people can assist you better?
your going to need to start by opening a terminal.

in your term provide the outputs of the following commands:

*first* with the ethernet cable plugged in:

`ifconfig`

`ping -c 1 8.8.8.8`

*now* unplug the cable, and replug the cable and:

`cat /var/log/syslog`

to start..  :)

you can save those outputs to a file if you add a `>` and a location/filename following the carret...

*(a double caret `>>` appends, and single caret `>` replaces contents)*
for instance:

*(let's say you want to make that output more readable to your helpers... lets add some echos in between.  echo simply create a new line if nothing is passed.  or it will echo(print, say, etcetc) things to the shell*

**the reason** for outputting all this to a file is so you can move it to a usb drive, and then use your internet connected computer to paste it's contents to this topic..  `:)`

---

## *simply do the following* **in your terminal:**

`ifconfig > ~/Desktop/troubleshooting.out.txt`

`echo ; echo ; echo '-----------------------------' >> ~/Desktop/troubleshooting.out.txt ; echo ; echo`

`ping -c 1 >> ~/Desktop/troubleshooting.out.txt`

`echo ; echo ; echo '-----------------------------' >> ~/Desktop/troubleshooting.out.txt ; echo ; echo`

*now* unplug the cable, replug the cable, and continue:

`sleep 12; cat /var/log/syslog >> ~/Desktop/troubleshooting.out.txt`

## copy the file

you will now have a file with proper outputs and hopefully signs that point us to your problem that the community can use to help you troubleshoot your issue... **now all you need to do is**:

- copy the file to your flash drive
- copy the file from the flash drive to your internet connected pc
- copy paste the contents to a comment...
- post, and profit :)

Comment: the file is too big for a comment

Comment: try pasting it to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and share the link

Comment: thank-you for the input, both wireless and ethernet connections are working.  I will troubleshoot system-network settings issue sometime in the near future

Comment: you could also try to reinstall the package (network-manager-gnome)